# Product Image folder

Tags: product-images

I tried creating my own folder for product image size. but in my case by default it is creating "70x" folder. I want my own folder for different image size. I aso want to know that from where magento is creating different product image size folder.

does anyone know how to do this.? Please help me out.

--edit--

i want that particular resize value for e.g."1200x1200" should be saved in my own folder e.g "p1/c:/images/img1.jpg". I m trying my best. but no results.

any solution for this.?

Comment: share your code, you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache folder is generated in the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image::setBaseFile`

```
   // build new filename (most important params)
    $path = array(
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath(),
        'cache',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        $path[] = $this->getDestinationSubdir()
    );
    if((!empty($this->_width)) || (!empty($this->_height)))
        $path[] = "{$this->_width}x{$this->_height}";

    // add misk params as a hash
    $miscParams = array(
            ($this->_keepAspectRatio  ? '' : 'non') . 'proportional',
            ($this->_keepFrame        ? '' : 'no')  . 'frame',
            ($this->_keepTransparency ? '' : 'no')  . 'transparency',
            ($this->_constrainOnly ? 'do' : 'not')  . 'constrainonly',
            $this->_rgbToString($this->_backgroundColor),
            'angle' . $this->_angle,
            'quality' . $this->_quality
    );

    // if has watermark add watermark params to hash
    if ($this->getWatermarkFile()) {
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkFile();
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkImageOpacity();
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkPosition();
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkWidth();
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkHeigth();
    }

    $path[] = md5(implode('_', $miscParams));
```

The `$path` variable is an array with all the subfolders.

and it looks something like this

```
array(
    'media/catalog/product', //hardcoded - somehow
    'cache', // - hardcoded
    '1', //the store id
    'image', //the name of the image attribute. can also be `thumbnail`, `small_image` or any other attribute you have
    '70x', //the resize value. if you only call ->resize(70) it will be `70x`. if you call ->resize(70, 90) it will be `70x90`.
    'asjdalsjdlajsdl', //an md5 hash determined by the values of `_keepAspectRatio`, `_keepFrame`, `_keepTransparency`, `_constrainOnly`, `_backgroundColor`, `_angle`, `_quality` and the watermark file an settings.
)
```

if you want to change this, you have to override the method mentioned above and change the lines I above.

Check also these answers for additional details:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76691/146
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/76589/146

**[EDIT]**
If you want images resized to `1200x1200` to be in a certain folder, you can modify

```
if((!empty($this->_width)) || (!empty($this->_height)))
        $path[] = "{$this->_width}x{$this->_height}";
```

to

```
if ($this->_width == 1200 && (is_empty($this->_height)) || $this->_height == 1200) {
     $path = 'p1/c:/images';
}
elseif((!empty($this->_width)) || (!empty($this->_height))) {
    $path[] = "{$this->_width}x{$this->_height}";
}
```

Comment: Thank u for the reponse..i want that particular resize value for e.g."1200x1200"  should be saved in "p1/c:/images/img1.jpg". I m trying my best. but no results. any solution for this.?

Comment: See my edit. I'm not 100% sure it works, but it's a starting point

Comment: any other way to try..

Comment: Did you try this?  I gave you a way...why would you need an other one?

Comment: yes i tried i am getting some output but not exact what i want